# How to make a .NET COM wrapper generic

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, interop, com-interop, installshield

I think this is a factory / provider type story but I'm not sure how to describe my problem.  It goes like this.

InstallShield has a COM Automation Interface that they change the name of it with each release.  If it was VBScript I'd say

```
set project = CreateObject("ISWiAuto15.ISWiProject) ' InstallShield 2009
set project = CreateObject("ISWiAuto16.ISWiProject) ' InstallShield 2010
```

once I have a project object I can do things like

```
project.OpenProject( filePath, readOnly )
```

In C# .NET 3.5 I add my COM reference and do the same things except now I'm tightly coupled to that class.  I want to be able to do something like

```
var project = CreateProjectObject( typeof ISWiAutoXX.ISWiProject )
```

But I can't figure out how to do this as there doesn't seem to be any shared interface to cast with.

Am I out of luck or is there a way to handle this type of a problem?

Comment: In .NET 4, there's `dynamic`, but on 3.5 I believe you're screwed.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that.  I'm only a small part of the build automation framework and I don't they intend on going to .NET 4 any time soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're only using .NET 3.5, the best option would probably be to write your own interfaces that expose the exact functionality you require, and then implement the interfaces using IS 2009 and IS 2010.  This allows you to use any implementation internally, and create a factory method (or use DI) to construct the objects.

Unfortunately, this does require a fair amount of simple pass through (wrapper methods that just call the COM object).  However, it's a very robust, future proof way of operating, and lets you work with a simple, typesafe API.

Comment: That's probably a good choice for my experience level.  Do you know any ways to generate an interface based on the types found in the COM wrapper?  I could then create my two classes and implement the interface and start wiring up the members that I care about.

Comment: @Christopher: I, personally, would hand write it - It's a bit more work than an automated solution, but has some advantages.  Just implement the methods and properties you actually are going to use, and wrap them as appropriate.  (Another nice advantage is you can name things more in line with your usage, which is often help, especially when working with COM...)

Comment: I'm going to give the answer to you because after coding several interfaces and subclasses I was getting further and further into my code.  But wow, that's alot of work because of the complexity of the API I'm wrapping.

I have to admit, it was a good excercise but I gave up.  I broke out some ducktape:  A cloned my class file that interoped with InstallShield and did a search and replace to make one Class15 and one Class16.  In the parent class I then wrapped it inside of a big switch statement so that only one of the classes gets constructed and called.

Comment: I will admit, it's ugly, and I now have to know to always make fixes to the one class and then copy and transform over to the other class but this code hasn't changed in 6 months anyways so hopefully that's my best ROI despite how much duck tape is involved.

Answer (score 1):

If you are so inclined you could customize the run time callable wrapper so the type names are constant

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to give up type safety, `dynamic` would be helpful, but you say it's not available to you.

But you can get pretty close to `dynamic` in older versions of the language, by using [a simple helper class to hide the noise of reflection](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/dynamicobject-wrapper/). It doesn't do everything that the `dynamic` keyword can do, but it still might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking round the issue I think I see a possible solution done a different way but its a bit esoteric.

References are part of the the msbuild (project) file in an ItemGroup. You can externalise this by having this particular reference in another msbuild file in the project included in the proj file.

Finally you can make this external MSBUILD file T4 generated based on some logic that looks up the COM interface and determines what the reference contains.

Answer (score 0):

Use VB.NET to create a strongly typed wrapper. Then you can call that wrapper from your C# application.